# Extract text block between slashes

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file with this content:

```
/interface bridge
add comment="Bridge VLAN18" fast-forward=no mtu=1500 name=\
    bridge-vlan18 protocol-mode=none
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] comment="Ether3" \
    name=cobre
set [ find default-name=ether5 ] comment="Ether5" disabled=\
    yes name=cobre2
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge-vlan18 interface=vlan18.bonding-ptp3
add bridge=bridge-vlan18 interface=vlan18.ether13
add bridge=bridge-vlan18 interface=vlan18.eoip-funes-vlan18
add bridge=bridge-vlan18 comment="VLAN18" \
    interface=eoip-orono-vlan18 path-cost=20
add bridge=bridge-vlan18 interface=vlan18.bonding-ptp5
/ip firewall connection tracking
    set tcp-established-timeout=10m
```

I need to extract every block of text from "/" to next "/", without the line of second slash. I tried the following (To extract "interface bridge" block):

```
sed -n "/^\/interface\ bridge\s$/,/^\//p" file.txt
```

But I get:

```
/interface bridge
add comment="Bridge VLAN18" fast-forward=no mtu=1500 name=\
    bridge-vlan18 protocol-mode=none
/interface ethernet
```

I need to get:

```
/interface bridge
add comment="Bridge VLAN18" fast-forward=no mtu=1500 name=\
    bridge-vlan18 protocol-mode=none
```

It is required to use native linux tools (grep, sed, awk, etc.). Any suggestions how i can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'f && /^\//{exit} /^\/interface bridge\r?$/{f=1} f' file

/interface bridge
add comment="Bridge VLAN18" fast-forward=no mtu=1500 name=\
    bridge-vlan18 protocol-mode=none
```

this should read *start printing with `/interface bridge` token and exit if in print mode and saw the next `/`*

Comment: This will fail if the record "interface bridge port" is in front of "interface bridge"

Comment: Adding "+$" does not work, no results. Without "+$" it works very well for me

Comment: do you have special chars after the text?  Do a `cat -A file` to see invisible chars.  Perhaps a tab?

Comment: Doing "cat -A file" it shows me: "/interface bridge^M$"

Comment: OK, you have a carriage return, change ` +$` to `\r?$`

Answer (score 1):

This is called a record, so in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) this gives:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="/";ORS=""}/^interface bridge/{print RS $0}' file
```

Here we define the built-in variables `RS` to be a <slash>. `RS` is the record separator. The output record-separator `ORS` is set to an empty string as each record already ends with a <newline> character.

The above statement reads, *if the record starts with `interface bridge`, print the record with the record separator `RS` in front of it.*

But this will match any record that starts with the string "interface bridge" so also "interface bridge port". A bit cleaner would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="/";ORS=""; FS=" *\n *"}
           ($1=="interface bridge"){print RS $0}' file
```

Here we also split the record in fields which are the lines in the record. The above statement reads, *if the first field of the record equals `interface bridge`, print the record with the record separator `RS` in front of it.*

Comment: I tested it and it works well but it shows me "interface bridge port" block too. It should be exact match

Comment: @jeb76 Yes I understand. Be aware that the solution of Karafka will also give a wrong result in case the section `interface bridge port` is in front of `interface bridge`

Comment: 2nd example it does not work for me @kvantour, no results when a run it

Answer (score 1):

With cut :

```
cut -z -d '/' -f -2 file.txt
```

Comment: With cut 8.22 I get this error: "cut: invalid option -- 'z'"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x` option in `sed`.

> x: Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces.

```
$ sed -n -e '/\/interface bridge$/,/^\//{x;p}' inputFile

/interface bridge
add comment="Bridge VLAN18" fast-forward=no mtu=1500 name=\
    bridge-vlan18 protocol-mode=none
```

Note, it will add an extra empty line at the beginning.

OR this,

```
$ sed -n -e '/\/interface bridge$/,/^\//{/\/interface ethernet$/d;p}' inputFile
/interface bridge
add comment="Bridge VLAN18" fast-forward=no mtu=1500 name=\
    bridge-vlan18 protocol-mode=none
```

Comment: It works fine! Which of the tools (awk or sed) would be the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\/interface bridge\s*$/{:a;n;/^\//!ba};d' file
```

If a line begins with a `/` print it and replace it with the following line. If that line does not begin with a `/` print it and repeat until a line does begin with `/` then delete it. All other lines are deleted.

Comment: It shows me "interface bridge port" block too. It should be exact match